# atmosphere-javascript long-polling not "refreshing" every minute

Tags: javascript, websocket, timeout, long-polling, atmosphere

Hi I'm new user to atmosphere, and set up a simple test that worked fine. We used long-polling, and the behavior was that my client would send the server a GET that would stay open until:

1. data was returned by the server
2. a minute elapsed

in both cases, the client would immediately send another GET for the server to hold open. Most of the time no data was sent, so every minute the GET would be "refreshed." I assumed this was the default behavior because maybe certain browsers or networks would shut off a GET that exceeded a certain time limit, so this was a way to avoid that.

Question:

Is this refresh controlled by the client or the browser? I poked around and couldn't figure out if the client was closing the connection on its own and sending a new request, or if it was the server.

The reason I ask is that the server got deployed, and now that refresh is no longer occurring. My client GET now stays open to the full 5 minute (default) timeout and then throws the timeout event, then reconnects for another 5 minutes.

Server team claims "nothing changed," ha-ha. So did I do something or what? Please let me know! Thank you!

request object:

```
    var request = {
        url: 'xyz',

        transport: 'long-polling',

        reconnectInterval: 5000,

        maxReconnectOnClose: 20,

        enableXDR: true
    };
```

Edit: the atmosphere server was changed from 2.1.3 (working) to 2.0.7 (not working) when the deploy occurred. When changed back, the 1 minute refresh behavior re-appeared. The problem is that 2.1.3 is not compatible with the server they are using, thus the down-grade.

Question: what is this feature *called*, is this the heartbeat or something else? Can someone tell me what change was made that would cause this. I've looked through the release notes and nothing jumped out at me.

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Comment: I honestly cannot remember :(  -- I kind feel like we might have changed the server so we could use the newer version, but it's just been too long a this point for me to be 100% sure that was the solution. Sorry, wish I could have provided a better wrap-up.